# How to do fractions

Tags: math-mode

On the math stack exchange, I've figured out I can do `\sin` and `\int` and `\theta`. I've also figured out that you can use `\frac` for fractions, but I'm having trouble using it. Can someone explain how `\frac` works?

I'm new with this so make sure a noob can understand!

Comment: `\frac{numerator}{denominator}` A quick glance in [math-mode](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode) will show you more possibilities.

Comment: $\frac{x}{\cos(x)+x}$ (testing) - like this?

Comment: @Kurtbusch yes.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question is basically about mathjax usage in websites (such as Math.SE), but fortunately, `\frac` or `\dfrac` command (for 'better' fractions) work with mathjax

Comment: N.B. On the actual TeX Stackexchange site, rendering of (La)TeX is disabled, which is why your test in the comment above didn't work.

Comment: @Johannes_B, how about adding your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 5):

Fractions in LaTeX can be done by using the standard control
sequence `\frac{numerator}{denominator}`. There are different
modes for inline and displayed formulas:

[image: kurtbuschFractions1]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Fractions in LaTeX? \blindtext
{\color{red}$\frac{12}{45}$} \blindtext
\[\frac{67}{90}\]
\blindtext% $\dfrac{91}{42}$ \blindtext%for the ugly output
\end{document}
```

You can use the displaystyle inline, if you really want to. But
it stretches the lines making the output looking ugly.

Package `nicefrac` makes the fractions looking *nice* which can
be good when typing recipes.

[image: kurtbuschRecipe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\begin{document}
\blindtext {\color{blue}Use 3 cups of all purpose flour and
\nicefrac{3}{2} cups of semolina. Mix in ehte yeast and add
water. Make a nice dough and leave it overnight at a rather cool
place.} \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Of course, you can use fractions inside other fractions as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\[ \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\sin{x}\cdot x^2} \]
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: kurtbuschFractions2]

It has to be said tough, that not all those commands may work with Mathjax.